# Problem animating the position of a GameObject in Unity while moving it

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, mecanim

I am working on moving a Cube across the screen when I press an arrow and display two different animations depending on if it is moving or idle.  I used a very basic translation to do this when I press the right arrow.  I have two different animation states that work fine independently.  One spins the cube when it is “idle” and the other makes to bounce up down in the “right” state.  Both are 1 second animations.  The idle animation spins the cube 360 degrees, and the right animation will move the cube up 1 unit then back down to its original position.  Everything works well by itself.  I included an image for the states for the animation.

[Cube Animation States](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHVwi.png)

In order to get the movement working with the animations I made an empty GameObject and made the cube a child if it.  When the cube is idle it spins, and when I press right it moves and bounces up and down.  The problem is when I release the right arrow the cube snaps back to its original position from the start of the last bounce animation.  If I hold right for 10 seconds, and release it will only snap back to the beginning of the most recent iteration of the bouncing animation (not to when I started pressing right).
Does anyone know why this would happen?  I tried changing some of the settings for the transitions, but it doesn’t seem like that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check that your idle animation modifying its position in any case.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't move the game object with animation.

you can have the rotate animation in the cube but not the translating part.

Because when the animations switch between the states the object will be moved to its original position.

solution:
-Create a script and attach the script to that game object.
-use translate functions to move the object